# How mod_jk handling node failure

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, tomcat7

We have configured mod_jk with two tomcat servers with 2 apache web servers. We wanted to know how mod_jk handling node failure or how it will do a health check.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watchdog by setting the `JkWatchdogInterval` directive. From the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html):

> This directive configures the watchdog thread interval in seconds. The workers are maintained periodically by a background thread running periodically every watchdog_interval seconds. **Worker maintenance checks for idle connections, corrects load status and is able to detect backend health status.**
> The maintenance only happens, if since the last maintenance at least worker.maintain seconds have passed. So setting the JkWatchdogInterval much smaller than worker.maintain is not useful.
>
> The default value is 0 seconds, meaning the watchdog thread will not be created, and the maintenance is done in combination with normal requests instead.

Answer (score 0):

In Advanced Worker Directives, use "redirect", this will Set to the name of the preferred failover worker. Eg : worker.server-four.redirect=server-two

If worker matching SESSION ID is in error state then the redirect worker will be used instead.

This feature has been added in jk 1.2.9.

Status of mod_jk

Please add the below tag  in mod_jk.conf file

JkMount status
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1

Then you can find the status of mod_jk by using below URL

http://webserverIP:port(from httpd.conf)/status